# AngularJS: Controller - Directive bidirectional communication

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create some custom validations for custom input components.

The directive of the custom input would act as a black box, so I can add the validations that I want from the controller.

To do that I add an attribute for the directive, called 'validations', p.e.:

```
<custom-input validations="checkEmail() checkIsNotUsed()" type="text" placeholder="Email"></custom-input>
```

With this example, I can define my validations from the controller as I want, with the idea that when I want to submit from the controller, it will check if this component is validated for 'checkEmail()' and 'checkIsNotUsed()'. To do that, I would need some bidirectional communication between the controller and the inner directive, p.e. using the email:

1. Controller wants to validate the component, so it will call the inner directive to get the internal input element.
2. The directive returns the Input to the controller.
3. Controller can check the input based on the validations linked to him.

I've tried different approaches, but I'm not able to get the final goal.

[Here is the example I've been working with](http://plnkr.co/edit/SdYF537aK16TD8hoDvQ0?p=preview).

**EDIT**

Solved: http://plnkr.co/edit/DMUVLifuWeGEuXOVfRwE?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would slightly question whether you need the directive as a complete black box. Firstly, usually you would need some validation messages or some information shown to the user on the different cases of invalid data, so just a true/false return value of any validator isn't enough. Secondly, you're also re-creating a lot of what Angular already gives you with `ngForm`, `ngModel`, `ngModelController` and the `input` directive, especially the `$setValidity` function of `ngModelController`

I would put each validator in its own directive that `require`s `ngModel`: one for email, and one for password for example. You can still pass options in from the overall controller however, but each directive is tailored to the information it needs. For example, a `validationEmail` directive can accept an array of existing emails used:

```
<input validation-email validation-email-used="usedEmails" ng-model="data.email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" ng-required />
```

Where `usedEmails` is an array of emails. The directive could be written as:

```
app.directive('validationEmail', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      validationEmailUsed:'='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelController) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
         return ngModelController.$viewValue
       }, function(email) {
         // Test the email and call
         // ngModelController.$setValidity(...)
         // to set the validity of the email
      });
    }
  };
});
```

You can see this in action in a [modified version of your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QyXlVX3xDgFv5YEaFD2M?p=preview)

Edit: If you want to integrate with server-side validation, once all client-side validation has passed from the directives, you can do it from function passed to `ngSubmit` on the form:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
```

Which can be coded up  using the fact the form exposes itself on the scope, and all its `ngModel` controllers (for the same of example, using a `$timeout`, rather than calling `$http` or a service),

```
$scope.submit = function() {
 $timeout(function() {
   $scope.myForm.username.$setValidity('available',false);
   $scope.myForm.email.$setValidity('emailFree',false);
  },500);
}
```

An issue with this is that you then might want to mark the input as valid after the user has changed it. You could create a `validOnChange` directive, to be used as:

```
<input ng-model="data.username" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" valid-on-change="available" ng-required />
```

and coded up as:

```
app.directive('validOnChange', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: '',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelController) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return ngModelController.$viewValue
      }, function() {
        ngModelController.$setValidity(attributes.validOnChange,true);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

You can [see this in this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TX0E4bOoUMimqD2efX0O?p=preview).

Another general benefit of working with ngForm, and ngModelController, is that it adds a lot of classes to the form and element depending on the error/valid state of the inputs, and exposes error state on the scope, so you can show/hide error messages easily using `ngIf`, for example.

Comment: This is good but I still feel like I don't want to validate until I click on submit. In terms of scalability this approach is not good enough, imagine that tomorrow I want to check with my backend if the fields are valid, I won't like to validate everytime I type but when I click on submit. So my question is, with Angular, is possible to trigger that action when you click on submit?

Comment: Also, using your solution I can't use a directive to customize the inputs, which I would need. I've tried to edit your plunkr, using nested directives, but somehow I can't communicate the inner input with the validations. If you can check it out and shed some ligth, I will really appreciate it:http://plnkr.co/edit/DB0a3rjaRhKk7NV4dt5v?p=preview Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @DreaMTT I've amended my answer showing how you can still set validity after the form has passes client-side validation from the directives and been submitted to the server.

Comment: @DreaMTT I'm not completely sure why you're making a new `<custom-input>` that then uses a template of just an `<input>` with all the attributes copied over. Why not just use the `<input>`, customised with whatever directives you need on it from the get-go? If you do need the directive, then specifying a template will copy all the attributes over to the new root element of it, so `{restrict: 'E', replace: true, template: '<input />'` may be all you need, as can be seen in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9rwUnrt7eZUULzq1vCjt?p=preview)

Comment: About the last answer, I'm doing this not to use just an <input>, I put this simple example to explain this in the simplest way possible. Actually the custom input directive will have some other components, like labels, some spans, and the final input. Thus, with this solution, it won't work either. Other ideas? Thanks again for your answers, I'm learning a lot from you

Comment: I'm not sure about the last 'Edit' that you made. Actually, I'm looking for an answer to validate when I submit, not when I change the model. Why? Scalability. If I want to compare with a .json file, which has millions of entries, I don't want to check everytime I type something on the input, but when I click on submit. So, when I click on submit, I will call the validation directive somehow and get if is valid or not. Does it make sense?

Comment: @DreaMTT I've [amended your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WEkrRjlXJh5WwAnyO9Ke?p=preview) with how you can added a directive dynamically to a nested directive: it should be in the compile step.

Comment: That's awesome Michal! The only thing I would need then would be to trigger this from the submit button and I will be done. Anyways, I'm going to try to solve this myself, I'll keep you posted!